# Merge to remote branch avoiding code to be changed

Tags: git, github

I could have chosen a better title but couldn't figure a better way to explain what I'm trying to since I'm fairly new to github.

So basically what I'm trying to accomplish is that I am pulling an open-source application off a github repo. I will need to whitelabel it to my organization so it will require customization. The problem is that an update is realeased for the application every 2 weeks and I would very much like to stay up to date.

What I want to do is be able to pull the update without my customized code being affected. Note that my customized code will most probably only do changes to the css and html of the application so it is very unlikely that those files are changed by the developers, but since it is possible, I would like to make sure that my custom branding is retained.

In general terms, I would appreciate if someone can tell me what exactly I will need to do in order to accomplish this. I have a clue that it has something to do with merging but I'm not quite sure if merging will serve what I'm trying to achieve.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The cleanest way is to create new branch with your customizations. You can do this by:

```
git checkout -b <my-branch-name>
```

Then you add changes and commit them to your branch:

```
git add --all
git commit -m "<describe_changes>"
```

When update happens, you go back to the master branch and pull update:

```
git checkout master
git pull
```

And rebase your branch to the master (apply updates):

```
git checkout <my-branch-name>
git rebase master
```

It there is straight forward to merge updates, git will do this. Otherwise it will mark conflicts and ask you to resolve them.

Comment: Can you explain a little what the rebase actually does and how it will function the way I want it to function? The way I'm looking at it, won't it also revert the changes that were just pulled to the master?

Comment: You don't do any changes to the master branch, so there is nothing to revert. Everything you do is on your branch and rebase find common ancestor of both branches and insert new commits (from master) at that point. If you are interested in git, you can read git book (first 3 chapters are really good): https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2

Comment: Gotcha.  Thanks a bunch! :)